# How to dismiss MPMoviePlayerController after stopping video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer, nsurl, mpmoviewcontroller

I have successfully stopped a video within 30 seconds. But I am not able to dismiss the  `MP MovieViewController` and I want to stop activity for buffering. I have used this code.....

Video Play Code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Pungi" ofType:@"mp4"]];

self.movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
self.movie .controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
[  self.movie  play];
[self.view addSubview:self.movie.view];
[self.movie setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
self.movie.initialPlaybackTime = 0.5;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(stopVideo)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

stopVideo :

```
[self.movie stop];
[self.movie.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.movie release];
```

Answer (score 5):

Put your `MPMoviePlayerController` in a separate class and load it:

MoviePlayerViewController.h

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h> 

@interface MoviePlayerViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

MoviePlayerViewController.m

```
#import "MoviePlayerViewController.h"

MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieController;

@interface MoviePlayerViewController ()

@end

@implementation MoviePlayerViewController



- (void)willEnterFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"willEnterFullscreen");
}

- (void)enteredFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"enteredFullscreen");
}

- (void)willExitFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"willExitFullscreen");
}

- (void)exitedFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"exitedFullscreen");

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSNumber* reason = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
    switch ([reason intValue]) {
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded:
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            break;
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError:
            break;
        case MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited:
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willExitFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enteredFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];



    NSString *videoName = @"Videoname";

    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:videoName @"movietype"];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];


    [movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 480)];
    [self.view addSubview:movieController.view];

    [movieController.moviePlayer play];

}
```

ViewController.m

```
    MoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:player animated:YES];
```

What it does:

`MoviePlayerViewController` is a custom class which loads an `MPMoviePlayerController` with a Video. in the `viewDidLoad` method (or wherever you want it) you LOAD the `MoviePlayerViewController`.
(`[self presentModalViewController:animated]`)....
This has the advantage, that your main class isn't overloaded with moviecrap/definitions and you can EASILY dismiss the `MoviePlayerViewController` when it is finished using Notifications to check wether it has stopped or not.
if it has stopped:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 2):

As code below shows, you should pause and set initialPlaybackTime to -1 before actual stop. This is one of tricky things that MPMoviePlayerController provides.

```
    [_moviePlayerController pause];

    if ([_moviePlayerController isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerController class]]) {
        ((MPMoviePlayerController*)_moviePlayerController).initialPlaybackTime = -1;
    }

    [_moviePlayerController stop];
    if ([_moviePlayerController isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerController class]]) {
        ((MPMoviePlayerController*)_moviePlayerController).initialPlaybackTime = -1;
    }
    [_moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: I don't know why would the player keep playing when i delete the second  ((MPMoviePlayerController*)_moviePlayerController).initialPlaybackTime = -1;

Answer (score 1):

You need to add notification observer in viewDidLoad:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```

Then add the method:

```
 - (void)moviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification:(NSNotification*)notification 
 {
    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.......

```
self.movie.initialPlaybackTime = -1; 
[self.movie stop]; 
[self.movie release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the some headers in your header:

```
 #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
 #import <MediaPlayer/MPMoviePlayerViewController.h>
```

You may also need to balance your "presentMoviePlayer" call with the dismiss somewhere:

```
[self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
```

if you are finished with the resource early, you may be able to release it sooner by using NotificationManager to watch for MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification.

and also

```
- (void)dealloc {
   [movie release], 
   movie = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerController` and `MPMoviPlayerViewController` are two different classes...

Comment: @Paul.s Yes. The MPMoviePlayerController is just a movie player, it provides a way for you to play movies on the iPhone, a MPMoviePlayerViewController is an actual view controller subclass that takes care of presentation of the MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: @Paul.s hence, MPMoviePlayerController is a property in MPMoviePlayerViewController that you can access.

MPMoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer is the property that you'd use to access MPMoviePlayerController properties.

Comment: I am aware of this. The OP is talking about using an `MPMoviePlayerController` but your solution is calling `dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated`, which applies to a presented `MPMoviPlayerViewController`

Comment: @Paul.s look my second comment and also call the MyMoviePlayerViewController  * moviePlayerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];            MPMoviePlayerViewController displays the movie/video using the MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: I am quite aware of how to use it and read documentation, but you have not explained this to the OP, you have just shown calls that do not belong to class they are using and not explained that you are suggesting to use the alternative.

Comment: For more information please review it ..http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated]; this method not dismiss moviewPlayerViewController